# logic required in onstart method in c#.net

Tags: c#

On using window service of c# I want to run the service based on my configuration tags, actually I will set the three tags of values in app.config as here below mentioned

```
<add key ="FIREHOST_TIME" value ="5" ></add>
<add key ="SETDAYS" value ="3" ></add>
<add key ="RUN_NOW" value ="1" ></add> <!-- 0=no, 1=yes-->
```

If suppose RUN_NOW value is 1,

when service starts it has to do work now and for next instance it should to run based by SETDAYS tags.

if suppose RUN_NOW value is 0,

when service starts it should not do the work it should wait for SETDAYS to come,then next instance should to run for every set days tag.

Here below I have pasted by code:

```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
     DateTime tenAM = DateTime.Today.AddHours(FIREHOST_TIME);



            if (DateTime.Now > tenAM)
                tenAM = tenAM.AddDays(SETDAYS);


            // calculate milliseconds until the next 10:00 AM.  
            int timeToFirstExecution = (int)tenAM.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;

            // calculate the number of milliseconds in 24 hours.   
            int timeBetweenCalls = (int)new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0).TotalMilliseconds;

            TimerCallback methodToExecute = kickstart;

            // start the timer.  The timer will execute "ProcessFile" when the number of seconds between now and   
            // the next 10:00 AM elapse.  After that, it will execute every 24 hours.   
            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(methodToExecute, null, timeToFirstExecution, timeBetweenCalls);


         }
```

So now I have to use tag help RUN_NOW and implement the logic, kindly advice how to perform.

Comment: your question is too high level and people may find difficult to answer logical question here you need to have better question.

Answer (score 1):

try like this. check the documentation for [AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx)

```
var yourAppKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RUN_NOW"); 
                      or 
var yourAppKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RUN_NOW"]; 
 // do something with yourAppKey
```

Comment: won't the `ToString` method throw an exception if the config value is not set?

Comment: No need for ToString as AppSettings.Get returns String. Another way to access item is AppSettings["Run_Now"]

Comment: @ravi i know how to fetch the value to code behind from the app.config, i want know that above if condition logic

Comment: @user1494292 that you have to think, we cant give readymade code here